# Android - Different MAC received from WifiP2pService

Tags: java, android, mac-address

Using the Wifi discovery example, every time a new device is discovered it is added into the UI list view, but before that the example app gets information about the device;

```
WiFiP2pService service = new WiFiP2pService();
service.device = srcDevice;
service.instanceName = instanceName;
service.serviceRegistrationType = registrationType;
adapter.add(service);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I begin the discovery search on my nexus 5. It finds the device.
Now, using the attribute `service.device.deviceAddress` I get the MAC address **80:6c:1b:44:5f:2d** of the other device on my nexus 5, yet when in-fact the other device's MAC address is **80:6c:1b:44:5f:2** ***c***

Why are these different? How has the `c` become a `d`?

Edit:
I obtain the address i consider to be the right one via the following code;

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
myMacAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
```

Comment: how do you obtain the address that you'd consider "real"?

Comment: Added that little code snippet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968951/wifi-direct-and-normal-wifi-different-mac/14480530#14480530

This post cleared up my question. (For any future use)